# Bootstrap get width of div column in pixels

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I'm setting up a page with bootstrap. I have the layout working perfectly but one of the elements is a zoomable map of the US (using d3). The zoom function I am using requires the width and height of the div in pixels in order to calculate how to translate and scale the map. I have tried using percentages but I can't get anything going that way. Is there any way to dynamically get the height and width of the div. I have searched all over but the search terms are too generic (or I'm not clever enough to phrase it correctly).

Alternatively, how else might I get the necessary values.

Here is my implementation using hard coded width and height (which won't work if the page resizes).

```
//make the map element
    var width = 1000;
    var height = 1000;
    var svg = d3.select("#Map")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chosvg")
    .attr("height", height)
    //.attr("viewBox", "0 0 600 600")
    .attr("width", width)
    .style("preserveAspectRatio", "true");

    cbsa = svg.append("g");
d3.json("data/us-cbsa.json", function(json) {
    cbsa.selectAll("path")
        .attr("id", "cbsa")
        .data(json.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path") 
        .attr("class", data ? quantize : null) //data ? value_if_true : value_if_false -- ternary operator
        .attr("d", path)
        .on("click", clicked);
});
```

in the clicked() function, I have the zoom like this which works, but only 
with a certain window width

```
        cbsa.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")scale(" + k + ")translate(" + -x + "," + -y + ")")
        .style("stroke-width", 1.5 / k + "px");
```

For clarity, I am ideally loooking for something like:
    var width = column.width() //or something using percentages

I can include my html as well if it helps.

Comment: Please include html code as well to debug easily

Comment: Sorry, I knew I should have. Thanks, philipp's method worked but I will be sure to next time.

Comment: ohk np Alec Daling... good it is working fine now :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can get the width of the column by calling:

```
var bb = document.querySelector ('#Map')
                    .getBoundingClientRect(),
       width = bb.right - bb.left;
```

Depending on the browser, the `bb` might already have an `width` property. Keep in mind that the column might appear wider because the initial size of the svg is too big, so its parent column might bee, too.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, I don't think I ever would have found that on my own. That's actually extremely useful to know.

Comment: Upvoted... but Hey ....I guess its getBoundingClientRect().....not getClientBoundingRect(). Guys who copy\paste might scratch their head few mins..... :-D